# Get the reference of an element

Tags: typescript, angular

Just to understand how things work.

Let say I have the fellowing code

```
<my-element #ref></my-element>
<button (click)="ref.classList.add("prettify")"></button>
```

It will throw an error, because `ref` return an instance of `MyElement`.

How I can get `<my-element>` as a dom element ? Am I forced to keep am `ElementRef` in my class and do `ref.el.classList.add(...)` ?

I tried with the form element too

```
<form #ref></form> // return a ref about the element
<form #ref="ngForm"></form> return a ref about NgForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@ViewChild** can be used to get an element reference as shown here.

```
<my-element #ref></my-element>

//<---<button (click)="ref.classList.add("prettify")"></button> I don't understand purpose of having this line. What does button do?
```

in Component,

```
import {ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent{

   @ViewChild('ref') ref:ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     console.log(this.ref.nativeElement);
   }
}
```

DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/uP7CYM?p=preview

Comment: `Button` is just for the example

Comment: Thank for demo, but what happen if the reference is an element not rendered yet (like in a `*ngIf`)

Comment: NgIf removes the element from the dom. And then if you are asking for such dom element (which doesnt exist technically) it will throw an error.